# Use of text messages to communicate between two phones through android application

Tags: android

Is there a way to communicates between application running on two different android phones without the server in between?
I thought that simple information can be sent using text messages which instead of going to user application reads.
Is it possible?
Also if it is, will it also work for iphone?
Is there any way other than text, I can use without server?

Comment: It will not work on the iPhone. Apps cannot read nor send SMS messages on iOS. You can send with user interaction though.

Comment: Have a look at parse.com and their ability to push messages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, you don't want to.  If you send a text message, it will appear in the user's messaging app.  That would be a bad user experience.  Also many users pay per sms message at obscene rates (compared to data)-  they won't appreciate it at all.

Also, remember that SMS is limited to 160 bytes per message, messages may not be received in order, and may not be received for hours (or never).  So you need to account for all of those facts when you write both the sending and receiving side.  So its very limiting.

If you do decide to do this, use port based sms.  That way it may not appear in the regular text messaging app.